# Java BitConverter equivalent

Tags: java, c#, bitconverter

Having the following block in C#

```
using (var nuq = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    var data = new byte[4];
    nuq.GetBytes(data);
    return BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 0).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

I want to convert this in Java. So far I have:

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
var data = new byte[4];
random.nextBytes(data);
```

I don't know the Java equivalent of `BitConverter`.

How can I convert data to `UInt32`?

Comment: Well, you can't really do that since there is no uint32 in Java. You'd have to use a `long`. Or Guava's `UnsignedInts`.

Comment: Ok, and how can I do that? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

When you get your random you can return a call to a method that converts the bytes to a `long`, something like:

```
public long bytesToLong(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
    buffer.put(bytes);
    buffer.flip();//need flip 
    return buffer.getLong();
}
```

Comment: From what java version on should this be working? Long.BYTES is not available in JDK6